# Randomize my gallery images

Tags: javascript, php

i have a website for using voting actors. i want to randomize my images reloading every time. i wrote this javascript source code for showing my images.

```
<script type="text/template" id="player-template">

<% _.each(players, function(player) { %>
    <div class='playerWrap'>

        <div id='img'><img src='<?php echo CANVAS; ?>include/view.php?src=<?php echo CANVAS; ?>images/<%= player.player_pic%>&wh=140,161&c=1' /></div>

        <div id='name'><%= player.player_fname%></div>

        <div id='viewinfo'><span class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-playerId="<%= player.player_id%>" data-target="#showPlayerInfo">Details</span></div>

    </div>



<% }); %>
```

how to shuffle this code images using JavaScript or PHP. i use this JavaScript code to randomize. but it shows only one image.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.playerWrap').length);
  $('.playerWrap').hide().eq(random).show();

</script>
```

Comment: you players array should be suffled

Comment: how to shuffle my array

Comment: Silly question, but why are you mixing PHP and ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

use this function to shuffle

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
   randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
   currentIndex -= 1;
   temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
   array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
   array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
 return array;
}

var imagearray= [2, 11, 37, 42];//here your object array should be present 
imagearray= shuffle(imagearray);
console.log(imagearray);
```

Comment: you didn't understand. I need an array of your images

Answer (score 0):

i modify this php code to view images

```
<?php

        $perPage = 6;
        $pageNo = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
        $offset = $perPage * $pageNo;

        $topVotedPlayers = $user->getTopVotedPlayers($offset, 20);

        foreach($topVotedPlayers as $topVoted){
            echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>";
            echo "<div class='playerWrap' id='player_{$topVoted['player_id']}' data-playerId=".$topVoted['player_id'].">";
            echo "<div id='img'><img class='img-responsive' src='".CANVAS."include/view.php?src=".CANVAS."images/{$topVoted['player_pic']}&wh=500,600&c=1' /></div>";
  echo "<div id='name'>{$topVoted['player_fname']} {$topVoted['player_lname']}</div>";
  echo "<div id='sport_name'>{$topVoted['player_desc']}</div>";
?>
```